# Is it possible to swap two cells content in numbers?

Tags: numbers

I have a couple of rows and I have to move some cells from one row to another.

Right now, I have to

- Copy/cut cell A1
- Paste it in an auxiliary empty cell C1
- then copy A2
- paste it in A1
- finally cut C1
- and paste it in A2

I actually don't have that empty cell to use it as auxiliary, and there are several cells which need to be moved. I would like to know if there is something like this, swap cells (or even better ranges) with drag and drop, but for Numbers

https://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/how-to-swap-values-between-cells-rows-or-columns-in-ms-excel/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use other cells temporarily, then do the following, which assumes equal size ranges:

1. Select the first range of cells.
2. Press ⌘C to copy the first range of cells to the clipboard.
3. Select the second range of cells.
4. Drag and drop the second range of cells onto the first range of cells.
5. Select the range of cells the second range of cells originally occupied.
6. Press ⌘V to paste the first range of cells from the clipboard.

Now the two ranges of cells have been swapped.

Note: Both ranges do not necessarily need to be the exact same size, however there has to be an appropriate amount of cells in the area of the ranges being swapped. Use your best judgement.

By the way, this works because the drag and drop clipboard is different then the general clipboard. So the first range of cells just sits there waiting to be pasted as the drag and drop operation didn't disturb it.

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically what you were asking for, but maybe it helps someone arriving here (like me): If you want to swap entire rows or columns instead of only selected cells, you can drag-drop on the row number of column letter until the entire row looks like it lifts off of the table, then swap the rows.