# Swap two columns/rows in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I would like to move column 3 in numbers in between columns 1 and 2. In other words, I would like to swap columns 2 and 3. This is possible in Microsoft Excel.

I realize this is possible in Numbers by creating a dummy column and copying/pasting, but this doesn't seem like the "proper" way to swap two columns. Additionally, this creates problems if there are other columns/rows which reference these rows which are being swapped.

Is there a way to swap rows/columns in Numbers while maintaining these references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has already an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298072/is-it-possible-to-swap-two-cells-content-in-numbers).

Additionally this can also be done by clicking on the column/row number one time (it should be highlighted), then long-click it until the column/row begins to float. Now you should move and reorder without deleteting references.